# Create divs dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom, html

I want to create as many divs as var foo.length, but my code only creates one div.

```
var foo = new Array();
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { 
  foo[i] = document.createElement('div'); 
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You should declare variables: `for (var i=0; ...)`. That isn't your issue though, the code looks like it should work.

Comment: Works fine, but only return one div create; i want to create 5

Comment: Your code produces 5 diffrent HTMLDivElement's no worries there. Also instead of creating the array with new Array();, use the more literal type []. You need to append the divs to the document or another container of sorts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling "document.createElement" doesn't actually add the new element to the DOM, it just creates it.  You need to then call 'appendChild'.  So something like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var foo = [];
for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
    foo[i] = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(foo[i]);
}
```